# workflow window foundation =()=>

Tags: c#, workflow

What does `= () =>` mean in c#?

I've used lambda's before but those empty parens `()` are throwing me off.

Familiar with this:

```
customers.Find(x=>x.FirstName=="John")
```

[Article resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358749%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: That's a lambda expression.

Comment: It is a lambda expression or an anonymous function. See MSDN reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for usage in C#.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote? The OP had obviously not met a C# lambda before and until you hear the name 'lambda' its not the easist thing to google...

Comment: @Stewart_R Actually, the OP [has seen lambdas before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245988/workflow-window-foundation#comment48593134_30246069).

Comment: @Servy that's this same question...

Comment: @DrewJordan Indeed it is.  It's a comment from the OP elsewhere on this question stating that he's seen lambdas before.

Comment: ah! and here I thought you had lost it :)

Comment: @Servy acknowledged. Athough clearly not in the same format or with enough familiarity to recognise one in the code segment he posted. I think my point about the downvote is still valid. Seems really harsh IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `()` simply means the anonymous method has no parameters. The way you're used to seeing, like `customers.Find(x=>x.FirstName == "John")` is the same... the first `x` is the parameter passed to the lambda. The parentheses are optional if there's only a single parameter, so this could also be written like this: `customers.Find((x)=>x.FirstName == "John")` With a method that takes no parameters, the 'single parameter' exclusion doesn't apply, so you have to write the `()`. You can see more [in the documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

The `=` before the lambda call is assigning the method body that follows to the `Implementation` property.

Answer (score 4):

It's assigning a lambda expression to the variable or property this.Implementation.  You have to break down the operators like this:

```
this.Implementation
= //assignment operator
()=> new Sequence { /* stuff */ };
```

The () is to designate that the method takes no parameters; the => identifies what follows as the code to be run when the lambda is invoked.

Comment: I've used lambda's before but like the following:

Comment: customers.Find(x=>x.FirstName == "John") but that empty () is throwing me off I guess

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a lambda expression. In essence, it's shorthand for defining a function.

Here is a decent tutorial explaining the concept:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda

Answer (score 2):

The `() => new Sequence` part along with the block below it is an lambda function that takes no parameters and return a `Sequence`

This lambda is assigned to `this.Implementation` so that at a later time you can call the lambda. E.g., `var s = this.Implementation()`.